# Can Resharper's code cleanup convert the conditional operator to if/then/else?

Tags: c#, resharper, conditional-operator

In the Cleanup code function, can ReSharper convert all conditional operator statements to if/then/else?

ReSharper 7.1

**Update**
Why? I don't like them. It is easier to read if/then/else statements.
No research? I did an internet search and looked through all the options, didn't find anything. Cédric Bignon's comment seems to confirm my lack of finding anything. So I thought I'd asked the experts here as I have been using Resharper for 2 days and thought maybe I missed something.

Comment: Check the documentation.

Comment: I have never seen this feature.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: In this case, to be fair - if it's not in the options, it's not available. =) You could write a search-replace expression that matches a conditional operator and replaces it with an if-then-else. But that won't work with Cleanup Code, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality as of 7.1. If you'd like it implemented, please log your request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response.